# Надо ли брать фразу «эффект бабочки» в кавычки?

Tags: кавычки

Сегодня читал научно-популярную статью о различных терминах и наткнулся на так называемый **эффект бабочки**. Автор статьи во всех случаях брал эту фразу в кавычки. Почитал несколько других статей, и везде авторы делают то же самое. На одном из сайтов учитель русского языка даже написал, что фразу надо брать в кавычки, потому что это крылатое выражение.

С одной стороны я понимаю, что сочетание двух слов используется не в своем обычном значении, поэтому кавычки можно понять, но есть ли тут другие правила, о которых я не знаю? Правильно ли их использовать во всех случаях? Примеры:

> Он знал, что из-за эффекта бабочки мир может измениться.

> Эффект бабочки — термин в естественных науках, обозначающий свойство
> некоторых хаотичных систем: незначительное влияние на систему может
> иметь большие и непредсказуемые последствия, в том числе в совершенно
> другом месте.

> — Майкл, это был так называемый эффект бабочки.

Comment: http://new.gramota.ru/spravka/punctum?layout=item&id=58_720

Comment: Крылатое выражение — это афоризм, который в отличии от фразеологизма имеет **законченную мысль** и взят из какого-то авторского произведения. Не крылатое выражение, устойчивое сочетание и термин: https://ru.wiktionary.org/wiki/эффект_бабочки Термины вроде бы никогда не берутся в кавычки (если нет родового слова).

Comment: Подобное: *эффект бумеранга*.

Comment: @oleedd, спасибо за понятные аргументы. Про "так называемый" тоже было интересно. Не знал, что после этого словосочетания кавычки не ставятся.

Comment: В Википедии "эффект бабочки" без кавычек, а "эффект бумеранга" с. Второе термином не считается.

Comment: @oleedd, если читать всю статью, то ниже "эффект бабочки" берется в кавычки, поэтому ориентироваться на это я бы не стал)) Вряд ли там кто-то проверял правильность употребления кавычек.

Comment: Возможно, что кавычки опускаются, когда сочетание становится полноценным термином. Может, время написания источников очень отличается.

Comment: Кстати, чем чаще употребляется фраза, тем чаще опускают кавычки. То есть происходит трансформация в устойчивое сочетание.

Comment: @oleedd, в общем, главное уяснил, что кавычки лишние)

Comment: Я тоже против. Почему? Потому что родовое слово есть (*эффект*), а родовое слово в кавычках как-то не очень, кавычки ставятся после (*эффект "Бабочка"*), а родительный падеж заменяет кавычки (*жанр "фантастика"; жанр фантастики*). Кавычки хотят ставить, потому что это эффект не самой бабочки, а связан с ней косвенно. То есть есть "за" и "против".

Comment: @Sharon Не полное? А какое тогда полное? Мне не нравится брать в кавычки родовое слово.

Comment: @Sharon спасибо, почитаю.

Comment: @oleedd  Какое родовое слово, о чем вы?  Этот термин для сочетаний  эффект "бабочка" с сочинительной связью, а у нас связь подчинительная (управление Р. п.) - "эффект бабочки".  В большинстве случаев кавычки используются, то есть пишется: так называемый "эффект бабочки". Почему? Все дело в том, что это не полное название научного термина, а только его краткое, но хорошо узнаваемое описание.  Употребление кавычек связано с  метафоричностью (то есть необычностью) условного имени. Все по правилам Грамоты.ру

Comment: @Sharon Это название эффекта, мы не пишем *эффект "Эффект бабочки"*, потому что родовое слово включено в название. Да скажите уже, какое полное название. Нет, это и есть полное.

Comment: @Sharon Читал, там не сказано.

Comment: @oleedd  Точное название: Эффект бабочки — термин в естественных науках, обозначающий свойство некоторых сложных систем непредсказуемо меняться при незначительном внешнем воздействии. Условное название. Эдвард Лоренц назвал это явление «эффектом бабочки»: легкое дуновение ее крыльев может вызвать большие и непредсказуемые последствия, в том числе в совершенно другом месте.

Comment: @Sharon Извините, но какой-то бред. Здесь определение этого термина, а не полное название. Термины в кавычках не пишутся. Могу предположить, что это сочетание не было термином и оттого писалось в кавычках, но уже стало.

Comment: @Sharon А кто говорил, что они не нужны? Есть "за" и "против". Но "против" более разумно, потому что: 1) термин (могли писать без, когда не было термином, а потом смотрели, как писали раньше); 2) родовое слово. Мне кажется, что РАН выбрала бы этот вариант. Здесь нет метафоричности, о которой говорит Грамота. Метафоричность — это когда не буквально, то есть когда бабочкой называют не бабочку, а что-то другое, например человека, который танцует, как бабочка.

Comment: @Sharon *научным термином быть не может* — "термин **в естественных науках**". Ну хорошо, тогда продолжайте эту традицию. Можем тогда и другие термины в кавычках писать, чтобы не отличалось... Я ж не против кавычек, просто говорю, что без них логичнее.

Comment: Ладно, обменялись мнениями - и прекрасно. До новых встреч.